# Problematic while loop in OpenCL kernel: Execution hangs

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, numerical

I wrote an OpenCL kernel that generates random numbers inside a while loop in the device. Once an acceptable random number is obtained, the kernel should exit the loop and give the result back to the host. Typically, the
number of iterations per workitem is ~100-1000.

The problem is that this code hangs when I enable the while loop and never returns a result. If I just disable the while loop–i.e. generating only one random number instead of 100s–the kernel works fine.

Anybody has any idea of what might be going on? The kernel code is below and also available at this [github repo](https://github.com/rsnemmen/OpenCL-examples/blob/5bdaa2df7455809566376430dcf2fe9ccbe50392/auger/cr.cl). One possibility is that the system (MacOS in my case) prevents the GPU from taking a long time executing a task [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443544/793218), but I am not sure.

```c
#include <clRNG/mrg31k3p.clh> // for random number generation

#include "exposure.clh" // defines function exposure

__kernel void cr(__global clrngMrg31k3pHostStream* streams, __global float* xa, __global float* ya, const int n) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    float x,y,sampling;

    if (i<n) {
        // Loop that produces individual CRs
        while (1) {
            clrngMrg31k3pStream private_stream_d;   // This is not a pointer!
            clrngMrg31k3pCopyOverStreamsFromGlobal(1, &private_stream_d, &streams[i]);

            // random number between 0 and 360 
            x=360.*clrngMrg31k3pRandomU01(&private_stream_d);
            // random number between 0 and 1
            y=clrngMrg31k3pRandomU01(&private_stream_d);

            // To avoid concentrations towards the poles, generates sin(delta)
            // between -1 and +1, then converts to delta
            y = asin((float)(2.*y-1.))*180./M_PI_F; // dec

            // If sampling<exposure for a given CR, it is accepted
            sampling=clrngMrg31k3pRandomU01(&private_stream_d);

            if (sampling <= exposure(y)) {
                xa[i]=x;
                ya[i]=y;
                break;
            }

        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you cannot run this in a debugger, I recommend you create a debugging version of this where you can pass an integer for the maximum number of iterations, say, twice what you expect to be the worst case. Then the debugging version would return all the sampling values and exposure values that were tested but failed to enter the true block.

Comment: I agree, setting an upper bound is a good idea for debugging this. `printf()` on the rejected numbers is probably also not a bad idea. I suspect you've probably got a bug somewhere which is causing *all* generated numbers to be rejected.

Comment: You are re-creating the random stream over and over again; perhaps it always creates the same output, which is why your while loop never terminates. Try creating the random stream above your loop that pulls from it.

Comment: Dear @Dithermaster, that solved the problem! Thanks a lot for the quick feedback.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then, for the sake of future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the random stream over and over again; perhaps it always creates the same output, which is why your while loop never terminates. Try creating the random stream above your loop that pulls from it.